# How to create an Android virtual device MacBook air with M1 chip? Your CPU does not support VT-x

Tags: android, adb, apple-m1, android-studio-4.2

I am unable to create a virtual device on Android studio on my MacBook air. For all the system images it says that your CPU does not support VT-x. What is the solution or a probable alternative t use a virtual android device on MacBook air with the new M1 chip

Comment: hawe you tried [THIS](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/my-journey-to-setup-android-emulator-for-m1-macbook-pro-b8365321b3e7) or [THIS](https://medium.com/techiepedia/setting-up-android-emulator-in-m1-mac-fff58ec8bff8)? plenty of solutions in web...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an emulator directly on Android Studio, not yet, although, you can use this repository that google created

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview

Here you can find the installers for Mac:
https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases

Just install as any other software and when you open the emulator Android Studio will, automatically, recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no official stable emulator supported for M1 macs. Things are still in the development phase. Information is provided in the previous answer. Until official support comes, I suggest you use a physical device for testing of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can create an emulator for M1 mac:

Android Studio Dolphin, build from September 29, 2022; includes arm64-v8a out of the box under the ARM images tab which works well with M1 mac.